# LabeFor doesn't generate display-lable class attribute

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

A new MVC project includes a Site.css which specifies:

```
/* Styles for editor and display helpers
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.display-label, 
.editor-label 
{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}
```

However, when I use `LabelFor(m=>m.SomeField)` the generated html doesn't include the class attribute:

`<label for="SomeField">Some Field</label>`

I have seen other examples where people are using LabelFor and the generated html does include the `class="display-label"` attribute.

Is LabelFor supposed to generate this class attribute?  If so, why might it be that mine is not?

I do have a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider wired up, but it is still calling the base:

```
protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
{
    var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

    if (metadata.DisplayName == null)
        metadata.DisplayName = propertyName.ToTitleCaseFromCamel();

    return metadata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those css classes are only there for when you use EditorFor and DisplayFor templates. When just using LabelFor, you need to supply your own css class.

Comment: Thanks, turns out those don't generate the class references either, but in checking out your answer I reallized it was actually part of the scaffolding instead of the Html Helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Rossis got me looking at one of my Create pages to verify his claims.  As calls to EditorFor and DisplayFor also appeared to not utilize any of these css classes in my project.  I started poking around the generated HTML of some of my Create/Edit pages and found the answer.

Those classes are only used in Views generated through the scaffolding options:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MeetingDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MeetingDate)
        </div>
```

So you can see the generated page explicitly references the css class.  It is not generated from the LabelFor Html helper call.  So the class references are a result of the scaffolding, not a result of the Html helper.

Thus I have to explicitly reference them in views that I code from scratch.